# Find the range of $f(x) = \sqrt{16-x^2}$

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

I solved this question using this method and got $\operatorname{Range}(f) = [-4,4]$

But as per my textbook, the answer is $[0,4]$, please tell me where I'm wrong

$f(x) = \sqrt{16-x^2}$

Let $f(x) = y$

So, $\sqrt{16-x^2} = y$

$16-x^2 = y^2$

$x^2 = 16 - y^2$

So, $x = \sqrt{16-y^2}$

So, $f^{-1}(x) = \sqrt{16 - y^2}$

$\operatorname{Domain}(f^{-1}) = \operatorname{Range}(f)$

$f^{-1}$ is meaningful as long as $16-y^2 \geq 0$

So, $y^2 \leq16$

So, $y ∈ [-4,4]$

So, $\operatorname{Domain}(f^{-1})$ = $[-4,4] = \operatorname{Range}(f)$

I'm pretty sure I made some silly mistake here or my concepts about functions are not clear.

Please let me know about my mistake.

Thanks

Comment: Square root is by definition  the positive square root, so $f(x) \geq 0$

Comment: $f(x)$ is a square root function....

Comment: Of course $f(x) \geq 0$ since it is a square root function

Comment: Yeah, so $\sqrt{16-x^2} \geq 0$, which means that $16 \geq x^2$ which is true for all elements of $[-4,4]$, right? So, why not $Range (f) = [-4,4]$, I'm sorry if I'm being irritating, I just don't get it

Comment: Your first step should be $\sqrt{16-x^2} = y\iff16-x^2 = y^2\land y\geq0$.

Comment: See what you got is the domain. But if you wanted a cheat you'd realize that that's a semicircle centred at the origin with a radius of 4. For the range you should consider that the square root function only gives positive values.

Comment: @Plato That explains  it all, I had one more question in which $f(x)$ was equal to $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x-5}}$, and my answer came to be R-{0}, which means the set of positive and negative real numbers, excluding zero. But the answer in the book was : $(0,∞)$, which excluded all negative values since the square root function only gives positive values!, thanks again...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you've let $y = \sqrt{16-x^2} \Rightarrow y \ge 0$

So this puts a limit on $y$ that $y$ should be $\ge 0 $.

So, you have $y\ge 0$ and $y^2 \le 16 \Rightarrow y\ge0 $ and $(-4\le y\le4)$

The common region is $0\le y \le 4$ or $y \in [0,4]$

Comment: I've edited my answer, please check.

Comment: Got it, thanks, I was really really confused...

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 0):

It is clear that $$16-x^2\le16,$$ which is tight.

Then a square root is non-negative, and you immediately get

$$0\le\sqrt{16-x^2}\le\sqrt{16}=4.$$

---

All values in that range can be reached, because the equation

$$y=\sqrt{16-x^2}$$ has solutions for all $y\in[0,4]$ (one such solution is $x=\sqrt{16-y^2}$).

---

Notice that this approach does not require to worry about the domain of the function.